# Python regular expression for file

Tags: python, regex, expression

I want to filter my file content with a RE.
It's a file about proteins, with for every protein some information.

Example for two proteins:

```
>sp|B3MGT3|AKTP2_DROAN  (266 aa)

Protein crossbronx-like.  [Drosophila ananassae (Fruit fly)]

MWYSIRNNQRMALIKQGYKILAEYRLVQDHLKNIYAIPSYASGLHWFGVIFVHSGIYAGSMFRFSILLPENFPDDTILPT

VIFNAAIFHPHICPHSKSLDLGPCFKEWRKDQHHIWHLLRYIQAVFADPEGSICTGKSPSGDLVVLDEVNNLEALNMLAK

SRPEYIKRIQELAISSRRHMYDKPMIEDPHYIIVEPYCAERHLRFMEQLKSPSWREATCEDDSPPAELLGHIDSSRQLDE

DEANQRGKLQAATTDLQHGARCSVAQ

      131 - 138:      GsictGKS





>sp|Q9AT00|TGD3_ARATH  (345 aa)

Protein TRIGALACTOSYLDIACYLGLYCEROL 3, chloroplastic.  [Arabidopsis thaliana (Mouse-ear cress)]

MLSLSCSSSSSSLLPPSLHYHGSSSVQSIVVPRRSLISFRRKVSCCCIAPPQNLDNDATKFDSLTKSGGGMCKERGLEND

SDVLIECRDVYKSFGEKHILKGVSFKIRHGEAVGVIGPSGTGKSTILKIMAGLLAPDKGEVYIRGKKRAGLISDEEISGL

RIGLVFQSAALFDSLSVRENVGFLLYERSKMSENQISELVTQTLAAVGLKGVENRLPSELSGGMKKRVALARSLIFDTTK

EVIEPEVLLYDEPTAGLDPIASTVVEDLIRSVHMTDEDAVGKPGKIASYLVVTHQHSTIQRAVDRLLFLYEGKIVWQGMT

HEFTTSTNPIVQQFATGSLDGPIRY

  117 - 124:      GpsgtGKS
```

I need to filter the information above, for only the proteins with the RE "[AG].{4}GK[ST]" in their sequence.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. This doesn't work... Does anyone know why?

   ```
   import re
   file = open ("ploop.fa", "r")
   motief = re.search("[AG].{4}GK[ST]", file)

   for line in file:
   if motief in line:
   print (line)
   ```
2. So, I need all the information (Accessioncode, name, amino acid etc) for the proteins containing the RE, not only the sequence. How can I do this?

Comment: You do understand that `.` has special meaning in regular expressions? Also, what is this `line` you are trying to print? It is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Well, the regex [does not find any matches in your text](https://regex101.com/r/hI5gS8/1). Also, you need to read the file to pass the file contents to the regex. What is the exact expected output for the above sample text?

Comment: For your first question, what is `line` supposed to be?

Comment: You should post a short excerpt (with the significant parts) of your file. You are trying to read your file in a wrong way, `file` isn't a string with the content of your file but a filehandler that represents a resource (your opened file here).

Comment: This is what the file looks like, for one protein: http://i64.tinypic.com/ejbo2a.png. So I need all this information of a protein, if the protein sequence contains the regular expression.

Comment: Instead of posting images of text could you just copy & paste example input to the question? If it's really long maybe you could shorten it a bit to preserve essential parts. It would make answering the question a whole lot easier.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify I have two questions: 

For the first protein you need to capture `crossbronx-like`, `Drosophila ananassae (Fruit fly)` and `MWYS...`?

Are there newline characters within the protein sequence as the example hints?

Comment: For this project I don't need the 'Drosophila Ananassae' for my RE. But the sequence, here starting with MWYS, is very important. That is the sequence I need the regular expression for. So I have lots of proteins, all with the information comparable with the two examples, and all with a protein sequence. With the Regular Expression ^[AG].{4}GK[ST]$ I must filter the sequences containing this RE. So, I need the information of **only the proteins containing the RE** in their sequence, but from the proteins containing the RE, I need **all information**, including Drosophila and the rest.

Comment: Eventually, at the end, I need a list with 'Species' and 'Accession Number', in the first example 'Fruit fly' and  B3MGT3. But before I can do that, I must filter because I only need the proteins with the RE in their sequence. Maybe then it's easier to understand why I need it haha.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that 'line' was from something else I tried. Also tried:

```
import re
file = open ("ploop.fa", "r")
motief = re.search("[AG].{4}GK[ST]")

for line in file:
  if motief in line:
  print (line)
```

Yeah, a dot should be a random token? I need it for a sequence starting with A or G, then 4 random letters, then GK and then a S or T.

Comment: What we're asking is how your lines in the file look like. For example, is it something like `AGTASTAGTCTCTCTATGTGTCTATC` ?

Comment: It's a protein sequence, not a DNA sequence so almost all letters are possible. (TKALLCKNFLKKWRM for example)

Comment: If you need to add additional information to your question then you should [edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/204922) your original question. Please use the "Post Answer" button only if you have found an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the variable motief equal to an re.MatchObject. Then in your loop

```
if motief in line:
```

will probably never be true

What you want is to declare a regex and then use re.search on each line to find if it is there.

```
regex = "[AG].{4}GK[ST]"
for line in f:
   if re.search(regex, line):
      print(line)
```

A list comprehension version to create a list of all useful lines would look like:

```
[line for line in f if re.search(regex, line)]
```